# I'm confused about what the second parameter to matplotlib.axes does

Tags: python, matplotlib, scientific-computing

I've been playing around with matplotlib.axes for a bit, and I'm confused what the parameter "rect" does.

According to the docs:

```
rect : [left, bottom, width, height]

    The axes is build in the rectangle rect. rect is in Figure coordinates.
```

I noticed what width and height do, it was pretty obvious. I tried changing left and bottom to a bunch of different values but nothing changes. What exactly do left and bottom refer to?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a case where `left` and `right` do nothing?

Comment: left and bottom are the lower left corner of the axes in figure coordinates. I suspect the confusion just comes from the fact that you use jupyter notebook and its `inline` backend where the figure is cropped to its content. See duplicate for how to change that setting.